# Google Charts API not working with uppercase characters

Tags: laravel, postgresql, google-api, laravel-5.6

I'm using the Google Charts API with Laravel 5.6 and PostgreSQL, but it seems like the API doesn't acknowledge the database columns name when there are uppercase characters, it shows the error: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column, but when I change the column name to lowercase it works perfecty.

Is there a way to manintain the original column name or do I have to change it?
This is my code:

```
$data = DB::table('users')
       ->select(
        DB::raw('Gender as gender'),
        DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
       ->groupBy('gender')
       ->get();
```

Comment: Unquoted identifiers are folded to lower case (despite the standard saying upper case) so double quote the column name: `DB::raw('"Gender" as gender')`

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you it worked!